# Is there a Windows 7 theme for Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: windows, windows-7, themes, 15.10, icon-themes

I am looking to make my desktop look and feel like windows 7, to make an easier transition.

Comment: There is also [this](http://sourcedigit.com/13721-make-ubuntu-14-04-look-like-windows-7-windows-8-windows-xp/) if you want. It should be valid with 15.10. Good luck learning. I found it easier to just drop it and learn new things but that was quite a while ago.

Comment: I would caution against going off the beaten path in this way. If you're that unfamiliar with Linux, changing your environment can disconnect you from tutorials that would otherwise match your system. At best, things will be harder to figure out. At worst, you'll break your system. If you don't like the Unity desktop, you can also try Kubuntu which is quite different visually, and may be more pleasing / familiar to you. Or consider Linux Mint which is Ubuntu derived, but very popular among first timers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try noobslab's Windows 7/8 theme.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install win-themes
sudo apt-get install win-icons
```

[Source](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/make-your-ubuntulinux-mint-look-like.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use to use Linux mint when I transitioned from Windows the cinnamon desktop was the closest to windows I could get without making use of themes. And it uses the same repos as ubuntu so check it out if you feel that you are not yet comfortable with ubuntu. Here is how you install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```